# How can this situation be described in a word(or a concise phrase)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I would like to describe the funded project of someone incompetent who has failed to properly complete it mainly due to his incompetence but who has managed to present it in its failed state as a success even though it is essentially useless and bears little resemblance to the pre-agreed specifications of the project.

Comment: I will suggest it would be a Presidential administration. Whose it is would be up to you.

Comment: @Elliot Jokes beside is there any short universal way of describing the aforementioned project?

Comment: A person who's capable of this isn't really incompetent. Anyway, an example sentence would facilitate zeroing in on the right word. For the moment, however, I suggest *gloss over* as in _X glossed over the inadequacies of the project_ or something along those lines. But like I said, an example sentence would be great.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of large-scale IT projects as well. Particularly private sector projects for government departments,

Comment: Despite the [developer's/project manager's] miserable attempts to cover their ass, the [project] is an abject failure. (??)

Comment: Incompetence is easily identified. I score it as a lack of due diligence on the part of the contracting agent. And if this isn't something you can put back in a box and return to Amazon, then it looks like the entire procurement process was inadequate.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence that would hold the word or phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's most commonly used in a political context, I think [spin control](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spin+control) can be used to describe  your situation

> The shrewd management of the way in which a piece of news or information is presented or interpreted so that it best serves one's own interests.

You could say

> The project was a useless failure, but the *spin control* made it appear as if the project was actually successful.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia, the phrase [smoke and mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_and_mirrors) describes "any proposal that, when examined closely, proves to be an illusion."  It comes from a common technique used in magic shows to make objects appear to float in the air.

In your specific case, you could say something like,

> He put on a great show for senior management, but in the end it was nothing but **smoke and mirrors**.

Answer (score 0):

He has presented a *simulacrum*.

> simulacrum: something that looks like or represents something else
>
> “ In other words, he prefers the bland, dumbed-down sounds which represent a diluted simulacrum of the real thing.”
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simulacrum)

> simulacrum: an insubstantial form or semblance of something
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simulacrum)